# How I can show in guildCreate the members and server Icon on discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```js
client.on("guildCreate", (guild) => {
    console.log(`I'm added in ${guild.name}`); //log console
    const embed = new MessageEmbed() //The embed//the embed
        .setAuthor("I'm in a new server!") //the author message
        .addField("server name", `${guild.name}`) //the name
        .setColor("GREEN") //the colour
        .addField("Actual servers", `${client.guilds.cache.size}`); //the actual servers
    client.channels.cache.get("779832833320681515").send(embed); //the channel of the embed
});
```

How I can see the members and server Icon of the added server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the Guild's icon using the [`iconURL()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=iconURL) method of [`Guild`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild).

```js
client.on("guildCreate", guild => {
    console.log(guild.iconURL({dynamic: true, size: 2048}));
});
```

---

Getting the members of the Guild is pretty straightforward. You can use the [`memberCount`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=memberCount) property of [`Guild`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild).

```js
client.on("guildCreate", guild => {
    console.log(guild.memberCount);
});
```

Since [`Guild.members.cache`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=cache) is a [`Collection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection), you can as well [`map`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=map) the members by any property you'd like. (Id, username, discriminator, tag etc...)

```js
client.on("guildCreate", guild => {
    console.log(guild.members.cache.map(member => member.user.tag));
    // --> ["Wumpus#0000", "entrynidy#1234"]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Guild#iconURL()

Returns the guild's icon URL as a string.

```
client.on('guildCreate', guild => {
  console.log(guild.iconURL())
})
```

#### GuildMemberManager#cache

Returns a **collection** of all of the **cached** guild members.

```
client.on('guildCreate', guild => {
  console.log(guild.members.cache)
  // Keep in mind: This will quite literally spam your terminal.
})
```